# Paypal Payouts available in the UAE

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

The paypal payouts is available in the UAE country but according to your document AED(United Arab Emirates dirham) currency does not available to payouts. I want to integarate paypal payouts for UAE.

Questions:

1. Does paypal payouts accepts AED currency for send, receive and withdraw money?
2. Does paypal payouts accepts United Arab Emirates bank accounts for send, receive and withdraw money?
3. Can i create business account by using the United Arab Emirates bank account.

Please answer above three questions and help us to identify the solution.

I want to integrate paypal payouts to UAE country.

Answer (score 0):

The currencies that can be used are [listed on the developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/reference/currency-codes/). Other currencies not listed, like AED, cannot be used.

---

Currencies are a separate issue from whether Payouts can be used with UAE accounts as either the sender or the receiver.